# Android Category to List

Tags: android, categories

I am new here,so I'll try to explain my problem in simple way...

I'm making and android app,but I'm stuck in one problem.
My app will gave category (5 imgbuttons) ,when I click on first imgbutton it will take me to an list.And if i click on second button it will get me to another list. The list will be the same layout,but i don't want to create 5 databases,only one.
I hope that you understand me.

1. Category
2. Category
3. Category
4. Category
5. Category

Click on 1. Category button
1. Item on list (1)
2. Item on list (1)...
...
Click on 3. Category button
1. item on list (3)
2. Item on list (3)...

This is a small scheme thank you for any help.

Comment: Like you are explaining me. Explain this in your question. You got better response.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you create 5 databases. You could have all your data inside a single database. As for the lists part; Since your layout is going to be the same, just create a list view and pass a different list to its adapter based on what ever button have you clicked.

e.g inside your onclick methods

```
    //if first button clicked
    adapter = new adapter adapter = new adapter(context,
    layout_file, list1);

    // else if 2nd button clicked
    adapter = new adapter adapter = new adapter(context,
    layout_file, list2);

    // and so on for other buttons
```

Between if the data type for all the lists is the same, you donot even need to create 5 lists. you can populate a single list based on what button did you click and pass the list to adapter.

Comment: Yes...i don't want to create 5 databases...but how should my Adapter return me the list from the selected button

Comment: Okay I'm stuck...so my Lists (5 of them) should have ID-s.
They are in the same .txt file(they only have Image and Text description)
The code should go something like this...

`@Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mType==1)
        {
adapter = new adapter adapter = new adapter(context,
    layout_file, list1);
        }
else if (mType==2){
adapter = new adapter adapter = new adapter(context,
    layout_file, list2);
}...`

But how to set my item have the same id as the button?Should i set it in the .txt(DataBase) file [id] = "1" or?